# Sistema de Login com Dominio

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Bom vamos ver se podem me ajudar!
Eu estou tentando fazer um sistema de login básico, porém estou com um problema, ainda sou iniciante em php e não sei muita coisa.

Estou tentando fazer este formulário funcionar corretamente.

```html
<input name="dominio" type="text" placeholder="dominio.com" autocomplete="off" style="background-color:#cce0ff;color:#00f;" />
<br><br>
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="usuario@dominio.com" autocomplete="off" style="background-color:#cce0ff;color:#00f;" />
<br><br>
<input name="senha" type="password" placeholder="**********" autocomplete="off" style="background-color:#cce0ff;color:#00f;" />
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Login" class="form-control element_style_9 event-submit-btn" onclick="submitClicked();return false;" />
```

será quem alguém poderia me auxiliar melhor?

Comment: Você poderia colocar o seu código PHP na pergunta? Para que pudéssemos ver como é a sua lógica para o login?

Comment: Eu ainda não fiz ela em PHP somente em HTML mesmo, pois como o sistema de login vai ser só para algumas pessoas eu queria já utilizar ela sem utilizar o banco de dados.

Comment: Então, não tem como fazer um sistema de login sem utilizar banco de dados. Se quiser fazer um, precisará usar banco de dados.

Comment: Então obrigado mesmo João por poder me auxiliar melhor, pois eu consigo fazer isso em JS mais eu não acho seguro.

Comment: Sem dúvidas não é seguro, pois qualquer um pode ver a sua lógica com o JS, e portanto, nem é levado em conta como sistema de login.

Comment: João tem como mudar de JS para PHP fazendo algumas modificações?? Pois eu não sou muito bom nas duas, mais eu estou aprendendo aos poucos.

Comment: Depende do que você tem feito com o JavaScript.

Comment: Eu estava pensando em criar um em php, porém nesse sentido só aprendi como enviar arquivos do input para o servidor. Eu até mudei o formulário pra ficar melhor, porem o problema do outro é bastante simples, tenho tudo feito mais ele não faz o login pois dá erro

Comment: Creio eu que está faltando algo ou tem muitas coisas erradas, espero concertar em breve, caso quiser dá uma olhada será que poderia entrar em contato comigo via o meu email francklyn97@gmail.com assim você me ajudaria no outro e esse daria como encerrado e posto uma solução nesse post através do auxilio do outro.

Comment: Cara, não posso te ajudar diretamente, mas dá uma olhada nesse [link](https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-sistema-de-cadastro-e-login-com-php-e-mysql/37213), talvez possa ajudar.

Comment: Ok João obrigado mesmo assim por tudo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

cara... para criar um sistema de login, primeiro você precisa criar um banco de dados com uma tabela contendo as informações como por exemplo "nome de usuários" "e-mail" essas coisas. depois de criar o formulário você precisa falar o método usado para transferir esses dados `GET`ou `POST` e a ação para a pasta de envio. exemplo `<form method = 'post' action = 'loading.php' </form>`.
depois precisa de um arquivo em PHP (no caso o "loading.php") para fazer a conexão com o banco de dados, verificar se o usuário esta realmente cadastrado e abrir uma sessão... de qualquer forma você precisa ter um conhecimento ja mediano ou até avançado em PHP e também algum conhecimento em SLQ (banco de dados) usando o PHPMYADMIN ou o console do SQL.